# PrefetchRowsAt won't work if no rows left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, prefetch

I am using the new `prefetchDataSource` of `UITableView` (also can be applied to `UICollectionView`. The problem that I am having is the following:

1. I am implementing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])` which works pretty fine.
2. I am using an `array` which starts with 15 elements. So in `numberOfRowsInSection` will initially return `array.count` which is 15.
3. What I want is for the `prefetchRowsAt` function to tell me when we're runing out of the rows, so that I fetch new data from my own source, append these data to the `array` and then `reloadData()`, which will in turn increase the `numberOfRowsInSection`.
4. Problem is that `prefetchRowsAt` won't go beyond row 15 because it is limited by the `numberOfRowsInSection` that I specified. So basically, I get stuck. Basically, when I am at row 5, I want it to tell me to start prefetching row 16.

One solution that I tried and worked would be to increase the count of `numberOfRowsInSection` to say 100, and then put placeholder cells while I am fetching the new data. But the scrolling bar will look too small as it is expecting that there is 100 items, so the UX won't be that nice.

Maybe the pattern that I use in step 3 is wrong (append to array and reloadData)? Or Can you think of another cleaner solution to the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem is. You should start the new fetch when your indexPath.row in the `prefetchRowsAt:` function is near an specific offset. Like if `indexPath.row+10 >= array.count` you should start the fetching.

Comment: @Lefteris yes, this is what I am doing right now by using 'cellForRowAt:'. I wanted to use the 'prefetchRowsAt:' to avoid doing that if possible, and also in order for the prefect to be dependent on the sizes of the cells, and not on a random constant '10'.

Comment: For the sizes of the cells, you could use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method  and see how far you are from reaching the end of the scrollable content and start the prefetch based on that. The `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol is meant for downloading data (like pre-caching images) for cells that have already been added to the TableView DataSource and not for paging.... [See the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching)

Comment: @Guy where is the data in the array coming from?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva network call mainly, and sometimes cached in the device.

Answer (score 4):

I think I has understood your meaning: Your class have an mutableArray to store your Cell's data model to shown. Everytime, the count of resource request back is 15.

- at first time:  the count of data got is 15, you want to pre-making the request of next resources from server when user scroll to 5th indexpath cell .
  After get reqeust, your mutableArray's count is 30
- at second time:   you want to pre-get next resources from server when user scroll to 25th indexpath cell .
  After get reqeust, your mutableArray's count is 45
- forever making request for next time resouces ,as long as user slides the screen

OK, **It's  not necessary that using prefetchDataSource(it is only usable iOS 10), rather than you can using dataSource.** .

Of course,if you only run your app in iOS 10 , you can making net-request for meta data(like pre-caching images) in Cell by implement prefetch method
. If not, you can use cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView) or cellForItemAtIndexPath(collectionView)

- For UITableView

  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
- For UICollectionView

  collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Futher, **I'm not suggest you using scrollViewDidScroll**,

Becuase the height of the cell usually varies with the change of data
 ,if it will be more expensive.

**your code can like this code below:**(UICollectionView)

```
@interface YourCollectionView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SDWebImagePrefetcher *imagePrefetcher;
@end

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // Check current indexPath

    NSInteger distance = self.array.count - indexPath.row-1;

    if (distance <= 10) {
        [self loadingMoreData];
    }

    // Preload the ten image into the cache, if you need your app to be compatible with iOS10 below. 
        NSMutableArray <NSURL*> *URLsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        NSInteger y = currentLastIndexRow + i;
        if (y > self.array.count-1) {
            break;
        }
        YourModel *model = self.array[indexPath.item];
        ImageModel *image = model.image;
        [URLsArray addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:image.httpsURL]];
    }
    [self.imagePrefetcher prefetchURLs:URLsArray];


    YourCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // setting your Cell

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    return cell;
}
```

**If you do not need your app to be compatible with iOS10 below,you can put prelaod code to prefetch method.**

BTW: If you think my answer working, please do not hesitate to adopt it : )

---

**#Updates**: About how to reload:  You can monitor array by using KVO, 
like:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"array" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and implement this method

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{    
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"array"])
    {
        if(!change) return;

        id oldC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
        id newC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        UICollectionView *cv = selfWeak.collectionView;

        // changes is non-nil, so we just need to update 
        [cv performBatchUpdates:^{
        // delete reload insert..

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // do somethind , like scrollToItemAtIndexPath
        }];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start loading your new data asynchronously and just insert the new rows: [`func insert​Rows(at:​with:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) instead of `reloadData` (you are inserting data, not reloading it).

You can start loading the new data as soon as the prefetch method hits the last row (or before). Once it's loaded then you can call `begin​Updates()`, update your array, insert the new rows and finally `end​Updates()`.

See more in the docs: [Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)

Answer (score -1):

Well, working of PrefetchDelegate is bit different.

You need to tell the tableview that total how many rows are there in your system.

so basically you need to pass the total count of object table view is going to display in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

Once this is done, **prefetchRowsAt** will start calling and let you know which row it's going to display and there you should apply your logic of API call.

Let me know if you need more clarification.